# Saving Add to cart items in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, e-commerce, cart

So I am creating something like an e-commerce platform. I am building the project using Django.

Now I have to make an Add to Cart feature. How should I make the model so that I can store the things added to the cart in my table that is connected to user table using foreignkey.

Specifically, I want to know that what kind of field should I define in my wishlist model to save the items added to cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sense to store such information on a backend. I most cases you can use `cookies` or `localstorage`.

But if you want store this information for registered users, device independent, you should create Model with FK to users table and Use that.

**Answer:**
Use M2M relation `user` > `m2m with fields` > `item` 
In additional data you can store quanity, order time etc...

[Aboud M2M with extra fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) -- django docs